# Using special code to confirm new user registration

Tags: c#, security

When someone will register on my site, he will receive a confirmation link to let him finish registration.
Idea I have is to make a column in table "Users" with randomly generated number. Next, I send a link to user's email, example link: http://example.com/confirm.php?user=newuser&code=54355345534
When he clicks on it, it checks his login and number from link wirh number in table Users.
It works OK, but i need extra column. Is this good idea? Second idea I had, it to use Salt as confirmation code, is this good or not?

Edit: Is possible to move this to https://security.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 3):

This is *probably* better suited for [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

With that said... what's the problem with creating a new table that maps "unverified" user-ids to a large random number (perhaps a UUID) which is then sent to the user via e-mail? The cost of that solution should be **minimal**, so I don't see why you would bother implementing anything else.

There shouldn't be any real problem with sending the salt, but that depends on how you generate it; provided you are using a good PRNG it should be fine, theoretically. Otherwise, it could be an issue: for example, if you're using a sequential counter or a timestamp as the generator of the salt value, then that's not so good. The problem isn't that you're revealing the salt per se, but that you're leaking information that can allow malicious users to "guess" what the next validation token will be which means they will be able to verify their accounts without having a valid e-mail address.

Comment: What if I will send a hash from salt as verification code? I generate Salt using C# built-in RNG crypto something (didn't yet looking for that class).

Comment: You should generate a unique value for this operation only (and expire it once complete and/or after a period of time). I'd generate a 64 byte (or larger) value using [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx). I like @Nik's suggestion of using a simple table just for this operation.

Comment: Why would you do anything besides generate a random number for just this purpose?

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know what the issue is with a distinct identification token. Storing it in a separate table (which will, normally, be *very* small) should not cause any performance degradation especially for an operation that's infrequent.